# Install XAMPP in Kali normal user

Tags: kali-linux, root, xampp

I want to install XAMPP, but it says to install it as a superuser and when I login to root I can't find the file in my home directory. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo *command here*`

This will run the installation as 'super user' from a normal account.

If you are having issues understanding procedures such as this, then I recommend starting with an easier operating system, such as Ubuntu or Mint, and working your way up to Kali.

If you cannot be bothered, then be sure to at least look into tutorials that teach people how to use the linux command line or bash.

Comment: Amusingly, Kali is root by default, so there's a reasonable chance OP's doing something else wrong.... I mean other than trying to run XAMPP on Kali, since there's better distros for the job and ways to run a web stack on linux

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I agree. But who am I to judge the user?

Answer (score -2):

By default in Kali you always use root account
But as you want you can execute this command
chown root:root /folder
Then root can see the folder
But root already have full access on all files/folders

Comment: I'm using standard user to do all my works so i need to install xampp on standard user